# error after updating R version (fscaret function call)

Tags: r, updates, r-caret

Updated my R version and tried to reinstall my previous packages.

Then tried to run `fscaret` package function call:

```
classVarImp
```

Got the following error:

```
Error in classVarImp(definedModels, xTrain, yTrain, xTest, fitControl,  : 
  object 'mySystem' not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `mySystem` symbol in the function `classVarImp` got [removed in an update](https://github.com/cran/fscaret/commit/30d26c8380a7d5f501b8f6067ea6142f74022a23) going from `0.9.4.2` to `0.9.4.3`. Try installing version `0.9.4.2` and see if it still works. You can do this by doing:

```
packageUrl <- "https://github.com/cran/fscaret/archive/0.9.4.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageUrl, repos=NULL, type='source')
```

Installing a package by Url will not install dependencies, but I assume you have installed this package before so this will not be a problem.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems like they removed the bug and updated to `0.9.4.4`. So the most recent one should work as well.